# update ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-2.2-froyo, android-listfragment

I have crated a class which extends the `ListFragment`. I have one button in a layout too , when i click over that button , i am deleting data of listvew , and firing the `notifyDataSetChanged` of adapter , but ListViewFragment doesn't get `updated`.

so how can i update the ListFragment ? i am using Android Compatibility Support Package

code inside ***onActivityCreated***

```
Button addTextTemplateClearBtn  = (Button)  getView().findViewById(R.id.addTextTemplateClearBtn);
addTextTemplateClearBtn.setOnClickListener(  new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(templateDB.deleteAllTemplates() !=0)
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "All Text Templates Have Been Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                templateAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }



    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awwww , i forgot to clear the List Array which carries the data of listView after  templateAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

so after clearing data , it worked !!

Answer (score 4):

call invalidateViews() to refresh ListFragment

```
listFragment.getListView().invalidateViews();
```